# Vuex action always has undefined parameters

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to call an action from inside one of my compontents on submit whilst passing some parameters. My parameters are always undefined and I cant seem to find my error.

Here is how I call my action:

```
<form method="post" @submit.prevent="postWishData({description, price, link})">
```

The insides of my components script tag:

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: "Wishlist",
    data() {
        return {
            description: '',
            link: '',
            price: ''
        }
    },
    methods: mapActions(['postWishData']),
}
```

My action:

```
const actions = {
postWishData({description, price, link}) {

    axios.post('/api/post/wish', {
        description: description,
        link: link,
        price: price,
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
}
```

};

If I set description, link and price inside my action everything works fine.

Comment: The payload is the second argument received by action, not the first. The first argument is an object containing `state`, `commit`, `dispatch`, etc.

Comment: @skirtle Thank you! I'm still new to Vue, can I just pass an empty object as my first argument then? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: The way you're calling the action is fine, you don't need to change that. You just need to change the signature of the action itself, e.g. `postWishData({commit}, {description, price, link}) {`. When you dispatch an action it doesn't just directly invoke the function, it wraps it in various other bits of logic and the payload ends up as the second argument. Exactly which bits of the first object you need will depend on your circumstances. In your current code you don't need any of them but for a real action (one that doesn't just log to the console) you would need some of them.

Comment: @skirtle I understand now, thank you for your detailed answer!